# Why would standardized betas be high (e.g. .66) but non-significant in moderated regression?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, spss, regression-coefficients

Running a moderated regression using PROCESS macro in SPSS (issue replicated by running the same moderation using mean-centered variables in SPSS linear regression command box), I am finding that the non-significant interaction term has a standardized beta that in some cases is higher than other significant predictors in the model.

Is there any common explanation for why this may be the case, such as collinearity, violating terms of linear regression, etc? I even calculated the standardized beta's manually by multiplying the s.d. of predictors by the b value and dividing by s.d. of the dependent variable, and the same pattern replicates.

(Correlation between the independent variable and moderator terms are around -.3 so collinearity shouldn't be an issue?)

thank you so much in advance for your thoughts!